# sentence index for getOpenIE method in coreNLP for R

Tags: r, nlp, stanford-nlp

I' using the R wrapper for Stanford's CoreNLP tools, specifically the `getOpenIE` method in order to extract relation triples. This appears to work fine but I'm a bit confused about the output. Whereas `getCoreference` returns a dataframe with a sentence column `getOpenIE` does not and `subject_start` and `subject_end` etc. seem to be in-sentence references. 
How can I determine the exact position of those elements in a document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at the XML output.  All the getOpenIE/getCoreference functions do is parse the XML anyway.  I had to edit those functions as well to get sentence information.